# Proof of the formula for Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I read on a forum somewhere that the totient function can be calculated by finding the product of one less than each of the number's prime factors. For example, to find $\phi(30)$, you would calculate $(2-1)\times (3-1)\times (5-1) = 8$.

I can't seem to get my head round why this works and don't know what to type in to google to find a formal proof. Could someone please explain in an easy to understand way why this works.

Comment: This was mentioned in one or more answers, but just to restate as a comment: the totient function is not always the product of one less than the prime factors; if a number has n multiples of the same prime factor, you use p^n - p^(n-1); in the case where n==1, you would use p - p^0 which is p - 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By definition, $\phi(30)$ is the count of numbers less than $30$ that are co-prime to it. Also, $\phi(abc) = \phi(a)\times \phi(b)\times \phi(c)$. Note that $\phi(p)$ for all primes is always $p - 1$ because there are $p - 1$ numbers less than any given prime $p$, and all numbers less than a prime are coprime to it.

This means $\phi(30) = \phi(2\cdot 3 \cdot 5) = \phi(2) \cdot \phi(3) \cdot \phi(5) = (2-1)(3-1)(5-1) = 8$. But $\phi(60) = 16 \ne (2 - 1)(3 - 1)(5 - 1)$ so what you said is not always true. It is true only if you have an order $1$ of all the prime divisors.

Comment: $\phi(4) \neq \phi(2) \cdot \phi(2)$ because $gcd(2,2) \neq 1$

Comment: @Cortizol Reworded.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the Totient Function is [Multiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192452/whats-the-proof-that-the-euler-totient-function-is-multiplicative)

If $N=\prod_{1\le r\le n}p_r^{a_i},\phi(N)=\prod_{1\le r\le n}\phi(p_r^{a_i})$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes and $a_i$ are positive integers.

Now, $p_r^{a_i}$ is relatively prime with any number which is not divisible by $p_r$

The number of numbers which are $\le p_r^{a_i}$ and are divisible by $p_r$ is $\frac{p_r^{a_i}}{p_r}=p_r^{a_i-1}$

So, $\phi(p_r^{a_i})$ is equal to $p_r^{a_i}-p_r^{a_i-1}=p_r^{a_i-1}(p_r-1)$

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems to be that what OP is asking is *precisely* the question of *why* is the function multiplicative.

Comment: @tomasz, even the accepted answer did not prove it.To me, the question was when we can write $\phi(N)=\prod(b_i-1)$ where $N=\prod b_i$

Comment: When it comes to the accepted answer not containing the proof, you're absolutely right. But still, the question does ask about a *formal proof*... nevermind. I think OP slightly derailed his question himself.

Comment: In any event, you probably meant numbers divisible by $p_r$ in the penultimate line.

Comment: If $n=p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then $\phi(n)=n\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right).$ Now, proof of multiplication is pretty "easy"

Comment: @Cortizol: Usually it goes the other way around. You first prove the multiplicative property and then the formula.

Comment: @Pambos maybe, I don't remember :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative explanation that some might find easy to understand.  The fraction $\phi(n)/n$ represents the probability that a random number $k$ chosen from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is relatively prime to $n$.  This event occurs precisely when $k$ is not divisible by any of the prime factors of $n$.

For each prime $p$ dividing $n$, let $E_p$ be the event that $k$ is divisible by $p$.  Note that $\mathbb P(E_p) = \tfrac1p$ (can you see why this is only accurate when $p$ divides $n$?).

The key step is using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to see that if $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_r$ are any *distinct* primes dividing $n$, then the events $E_{p_1}, E_{p_2}, \ldots, E_{p_r}$ are **independent**: being even does not affect your chances of being divisible by $3$ (again, note that this is only precisely true because $n$ is a multiple of the LCM of those primes).

In particular we might as well choose $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_r$ to be *all* the primes dividing $n$.  In this case, since $\phi(n)/n$ is the probability that none of these events occur, we have

$$\frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \mathbb P(\overline{E_{p_1}} \cap \overline{E_{p_2}} \cap \cdots\cap\overline{E_{p_r}}) =  \mathbb P(\overline{E_{p_1}})\mathbb P(\overline{E_{p_2}})\cdots \mathbb P(\overline{E_{p_r}}) = (1-\tfrac1{p_1})(1-\tfrac1{p_2})\cdots(1-\tfrac1{p_r}).$$

Answer (score 3):

This work **only** if $n$ is [squarefree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) ($30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ is squarefree).
 
It can be proved that if $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdot p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$ (where $p_i$ are primes with $p_i\neq p_j \ \forall i\neq j$) then 
$$\phi(n)=p_1^{k_1-1}\cdot p_2^{k_2-1}\cdots p_r^{k_r-1}\cdot(p_1-1)\cdot(p_2-1)\cdots(p_r-1).$$
Therefore if $n$ is squarefree integer, meaning that $k_i=1 \ \forall \ i=1,2,\ldots r$,$$\phi(n)=(p_1-1)\cdot(p_2-1)\cdots(p_r-1).$$

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#.CF.86.28n.29_is_multiplicative).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Examining the units (invertibles) in the CRT decomposition $\rm\: \Bbb Z/n \cong \Bbb Z/p^j \oplus \cdots \oplus \Bbb Z/q^k \:$ shows that $\rm\:\phi(n) = \phi(p^j)\cdots \phi(q^k),\:$ and one easily shows $\rm\:\phi(p^j) = p^j - p^{j-1} = p^{j-1}(p-1)\:$ by counting (non)units  mod $\rm\,p^j;$  they are integers in $\rm[1,p^j]$ that are not coprime to $\rm\,p,\,$ hence they are precisely the $\rm\,\color{#C00}{p^{j-1}}$ multiples of $\rm\,p \le p^j,\:$ i.e. $\rm\: \color{#C00}1\cdot p,\: \color{#C00}2\cdot p,\ldots,\:\color{#C00}{p^{j-1}}\cdot p.$

Comment: Why did you \rm your math?

Comment: @tomasz Why do you italicize yours?

Comment: Because that's the standard convention. Makes it easier to tell words and variables apart.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this is not necessarily the case, but there is a general formula for the Euler function:

Given the prime factorization of some number $n = p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2} \cdots p_r^{t_r}$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$), the number of relatively prime numbers to $n$ is $$ \varphi(n) = n \cdot p_1^{t_1 - 1}(p_1 - 1)p_2^{t_2 - 1}(p_2 - 2) \cdots p_r^{t_r - 1}(p_r - 1) = n \cdot \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_1}\right) \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_2}\right) \cdots \left(1 -\dfrac{1}{p_r} \right)$$

More on this formula and some of its proofs can be found at the following sites:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/3000/notes-MR/Gerstein-6-6.pdf

[https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/F03/Class17.pdf](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/F03/Class17.pdf)

, but I think it's an interesting function, so I will walk through the proof as well.

***Proof:***

In this proof, we will utilize the principle of inclusion-exclusion and consider the numbers **not** relatively prime to $n$. So $$C = \{ k \in \{1,...,n\} : gcd(n, k) = 1\}$$ $(k < m)$ is the set of all numbers relatively prime to $n$ and we'll let $$\overline{C} = \{ k \in \{1,...,n\} : gcd(n, k) \neq 1\}$$ be the complement of $C$ meaning in consists of all numbers not relatively prime to $n$.

By the prime factorization theorem, we know $n$ has a unique prime factorization, $n = p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2} \cdots p_r^{t_r}$. If some natural number $k$ less than or equal $n$ is not relatively prime to $n$, then $gcd(n, k) \neq 1$ and it is a multiple of at least one prime number $p_i$ in the prime factorization of $n$ (otherwise, the number could not be less than $n$).

We will now define $$\overline{C}_i = \{k \in \{1,...,n\} : p_i \mid k\}$$ $(i \in \{1, ...,r\}$ such that $\overline{C} = \overline{C}_1 \cup \overline{C}_2 \cup \cdots \cup \overline{C}_r$. In other words, $\overline{C}_i$ is the set of all multiples of $p_i$ less than or equal to $n$, and the cardinality of this set is $\dfrac{n}{p_i}$ (we know $\dfrac{n}{p_i} \in \mathbb{N}$ because $p_i$ is in the prime factorization of $n$). Let's extend this logic to an arbitrary intersection: $$\overline{C}_{i_1} \cap \overline{C}_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap \overline{C}_{i_k} = \{ k \in \{1, ..., n\} : p_{i_1}p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k} \mid n\}\: (i_j \in \{1,...,n\}, j \in \{1,...,k\}, \text{ and } k \leq r)$$ The interpretation of this intersection is the set of numbers divisible by the primes $p_{i_1}, p_{i_2}, ..., p_{i_k}$. Thus, $$| \overline{C}_{i_1} \cap \overline{C}_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap \overline{C}_{i_k} | =  \dfrac{n}{p_{i_1}p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k}}$$.

Now, to find the total number of natural numbers relatively prime to $n$ we'll want to subtract the total number of natural numbers not relatively prime to $n$ from the total number of natural numbers less than or equal to $n$ (which is just $n$). But to obtain the number of natural numbers not relatively prime to $n$, we cannot simply sum together the sizes of the previously defined arbitrary intersections, though, because there is some overlap between them (an integer can appear in several arbitrary intersections given that it has more than one prime number in its prime factorization). Instead, we need $|\overline{C}_1 \cup \overline{C}_2 \cup \cdots \cup \overline{C}_r|$, which we obtain through the principle of inclusion-exclusion:

$$ \begin{align*}
                 \varphi (n) = |C| = n - |\overline{C}_1 \cup \overline{C}_2 \cup \cdots \cup \overline{C}_r | &= n - \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^r (-1)^{k - 1} \displaystyle\sum_{I \in {\{1, ..., r\} \choose k}} \left\lvert \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{C}_i \right\rvert\\
                 &= n - \displaystyle\sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1,...,r\}} (-1)^{|I| - 1} \left\lvert \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{C}_i \right\rvert\\
\text{(distribute -1)}\:\:  &= n + \displaystyle\sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1,...,r\}} (-1)^{|I|} \left\lvert \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{C}_i \right\rvert\\
\text{(substitute formula for size of arbitrary intersection)} &= n +  \displaystyle\sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1,...,r\}} (-1)^{|I|} \dfrac{n}{\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} p_i}\\
                 &= n \cdot (1 +  \displaystyle\sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1,...,r\}} (-1)^{|I|} \dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} p_i}\\
                 \left( \dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} p_i} \text{is 1 for } I = \emptyset \right) \: \: &= n \cdot \displaystyle\sum_{I \subseteq \{1,...,r\}} (-1)^{|I|} \dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} p_i}\\
                 &= n \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_1} \right)\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_2} \right) \cdots \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_r} \right)\\
   \end{align*} $$

The last step uses the following identity when $x_i = -\dfrac{1}{p_i}$:

$$(1 + x_1)(1 + x_2) \cdots (1 + x_n) = \displaystyle\sum_{I \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}} \displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} x_i$$