# Euler's phi function

Tags: group-theory, totient-function

I have attempted a problem which required me to use Euler's phi function. In doing so I have assumed that $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y).$

Am I right to do this or have I made a mistake?

Comment: That's true only if $\;x,y\;$ are coprime.

Comment: Phi function is multiplicative only when x & y are relative primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this only if $x,y$ are coprime.

E.g. see this post:

[What's the proof that the Euler totient function is multiplicative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192452/whats-the-proof-that-the-euler-totient-function-is-multiplicative)

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, that is, they have no common divisors, then this is true. However, in general it is false.

For example, for $x = y = 3$, we have that $\phi(x) = \phi(y) = \phi(3) = 2$ but $\phi(xy) = \phi(9) = 6$.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is expressed by the language that $\varphi $ is *multiplicative*, but not *completely multiplicative*.

It is essentially the Chinese remainder theorem, which tells us that when $(x,y)=1$, we have $\varphi (xy)=\varphi  (x)\varphi  (y) $.

(It is not always true without the restriction that $x $ and $y $ are co-prime.)