# Show that if n is even and $n≥ 2$ then $\phi(n)≤ n/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently working in the following Euler's theorem exercise:

> Show that if n is even and $n≥2$ then $\phi(n)≤ n/2$

I'm starting from the point that if $n$ is even at least one of its factors is $2$ but still can't find a way to show the required fact, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Given that $n$ is even, are there any numbers you can say are definitely *not* coprime to $n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $n$ is even, any even number that's less than or equal $n$ is not coprime to $n$. There are $\frac n2$ of them. The inequality follows.

Answer (score 2):

Given $n$ is even, all the even numbers less than or equal to $n$ must not be coprime to $n$.  There are $\frac n2$ such.  $\therefore \phi(n)\le n-\frac n2=\frac n2$.

Answer (score 2):

For $k\ge1,$

$\phi(2^km)=\phi(2^k)\phi(m)=?$ for odd $m$

Now $\phi(m)\le m-1$

Comment: Do you mean in the second line "for even $m$"?

Comment: @mraz, No, I've used https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192452/whats-the-proof-that-the-euler-totient-function-is-multiplicative

Comment: Got it, thank you