# proving multiplicative property of Euler's totient function

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove that Euler's $\phi$ function is multiplicative i.e. $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$ when m and n are coprime. A key step in the proof is this:

$A = \{a \mid 1 ≤ a < m, \gcd(a, m) = 1\}$

$B = \{b\mid  1 ≤ b < n, \gcd(b, n) = 1\}$

$C = \{c \mid 1 ≤ c < mn, \gcd(c, mn) = 1\}.$

Then we have that |A| = φ(m), |B| = φ(n), and |C| = φ(m × n). I need to show that C has equally many elements as the set A × B = {(a, b) | a ∈ A, b ∈ B}, from which the claim follows. By using the Chinese remainder theorem by which the mapping $\mathbb{Z}_{mn} → \mathbb{Z}_m × \mathbb{Z}_n$, is bijective in case of m and n coprime. Now it should be enough to prove that $A ⊂ \mathbb{Z}_{m}$, $B ⊂ \mathbb{Z}_n$, and $C ⊂ \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$. I'm not able to prove it. Could you clarify what's the relation between the sets A,B, and C and the quotient set $\mathbb{Z}_{x}$?

Comment: Isn't $A\subset \mathbb{Z}_m$ obvious ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the proof that the Euler totient function is multiplicative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192452/whats-the-proof-that-the-euler-totient-function-is-multiplicative)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in $\mathbb{Z}_m ×\mathbb{Z}_n $ the  the elements $(a,b)$ of order $mn$ have to satisfy $gcd(m,a)=gcd(n,b)=1$ ?

How many such elements do we get ? Is that $\phi(m)\phi(n)$ ?

Again in $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ , there are  $\phi(mn)$  elements are of order $mn$ .

Due to the bijectivity of the map(the one you  mentioned), shouldn't these numbers be equal ?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping $\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$, is not only bijective, but it is a *ring isomorphism*, whence an induced group isomorphism of the groups of units:
\begin{align}
(\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z)^\times&\longrightarrow (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times\times(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times, \\
x+mn\mathbf Z&\longmapsto (x+m\mathbf Z,x+n\mathbf Z).
\end{align}
Now $A, B, C$ are simply the sets of canonical representative of the congruence classes of the multiplicative groups of units in $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z, \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ and $\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z$ respectively.